# How can recognize a custom field programmatically?

Tags: c#, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-2016

In Microsoft Dynamics 365, I need to find **custom fields** in an entity, I want to get custom fields of an entity with odata(rest api) or with SDK for dynamic purpose.
Is there any way to find out as programmatically method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily enumerate the customization prefixes of all publishers in your instance by querying the `publisher` table, you want the column named `customizationprefix`.

Once you have retrieved all the prefixes, you can filter the result of a `RetrieveEntityRequest` to extract all the columns where the `name` starts with `"<customizationprefix>_"`.

Prefixes like `adx`, `cc` and `msdyn` come from add-ons (Portal, Marketing, Field Service etc.), you might want to cherry pick the list of prefixes depending on your specific needs.

Sample code:

```
var client = new CrmServiceClient( /* ... */ );
const string ENTITY_TO_CHECK = "account";   // logical name

var prefixesQuery = new QueryExpression("publisher") { 
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("customizationprefix")
};
var prefixesData = client.RetrieveMultiple(prefixesQuery).Entities
  ?.Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>("customizationprefix"));

Console.WriteLine("Publisher prefixes:");
foreach (var pd in prefixesData)
  Console.WriteLine("> {0}", pd);

var columnsQuery = new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
  LogicalName = ENTITY_TO_CHECK,
  EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
  RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

var columnsData = (client.Execute(columnsQuery) as RetrieveEntityResponse)?.EntityMetadata?.Attributes
  ?.Where(col => prefixesData.Any(prefix => col.LogicalName.StartsWith($"{prefix}_")))
  .OrderBy(col => col.LogicalName);

Console.WriteLine("{0} custom fields: {1}", ENTITY_TO_CHECK, columnsData.Count());
foreach (var cd in columnsData.Take(1))
  Console.WriteLine("> {0}", cd.LogicalName);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is it might side effect on performance in runtime?

Comment: In this scenario, not really